# Доенная / доеная

Tags: орфография

Правильно писать как? Наверное, первый вариант правильный.

`Доеная коза.`

`Доенная коза.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта верны:

***Доёная** коза* — прил., коза без молока, с пустым выменем.

***Доенная** коза* — прич., коза, которую подоили.

**Орфографический словарь**

доёный, прил.

доенный; кр. ф. доен, доена, прич.

**Примеры предложений**:

[https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/доёный](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

[https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/доенный](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: Но *доить* – это же несовершённый вид, а следовательно, надо писать, если нет зависимых слов или префикса, *доеный*. Почему не так-таки-с?

Comment: Иногда эти  правила не действуют (они же формальные)!
В ряде случаев формальное решение орфограммы заменяется смысловым решением,  а именно: две буквы НН пишутся в причастиях, образованных от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида, если они обозначают не качественный признак, а признак по действию.  Это касается, к примеру,  глаголов  "топить, кормить",   Надо смотреть по словарю.

Comment: *Топлёный шоколад*, но *топленный корабль*, что ли?

Comment: А где написано это правило, про которое вы говорите?

Comment: Говорят, что надо писать *кормленый*.

Comment: Говорят много чего, можно ли всем доверять. И зачем вам правило, если есть орфографический словарь. Также вы знаете признаки различения прилагательных и причастий (качество или действие).  А еще можно посмотреть примеры из литературы. Этого достаточно для того, чтобы  вы составили "правило для себя".  Да и какое это правило? Просто эмпирический вывод.

Comment: Что насчёт моих примеров с *топить*?

Comment: Я отвечу в новой теме, но сначала послушаю остальных.